# How would I evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty}x\int_0^{1/x}e^t \cos(t) \space \text{d}t$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I need to evaluate $$\lim_{x \to \infty}x\int_0^{1/x}e^t \cos(t) \space \text{d}t$$ and I'm not really sure how to start. Do I have to find the integral or is there another way to figure it out?

Comment: Hint: Try L'Hopital's rule on $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\int_0^{\frac{1}{x}} e^t\cos t\,dt}{\frac{1}{x}}.$$

Comment: You are dealing with a limit of the form $\infty\cdot0$, so the natural solution would be to apply l'Hopital.

Comment: What if I haven't learned l'Hopital's rule? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $u = 1/x$, your limit is the same as

$$\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\int_0^u e^t\cos t\, dt}{u},$$

which by L'hospital's rule and fundamental theorem of calculus is

$$\lim_{u\to 0}  \frac{e^u \cos u}{1} = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is asking for the average value of $f(t)=e^t\cos t$ over the interval $[0,1/x]$.  Since $f(t)$ is continuous everywhere, its average value on a small interval near zero approaches $f(0)$, namely $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is through L'Hospital's Rule and the Fundamental Theorem. But there are more complicated ways.
We examine 
$$\int_0^{1/x}e^t\cos t\,dt$$
for large positive $x$. Note that $e^t\cos t$ is increasing in the interval $(0,\pi/4)$ (look at the derivative). So if $x$ is large, and $0\le t\le 1/x$, we have $e^t\cos t\lt e^{1/x}\cos(1/x)$. It follows that
$$\frac{1}{x}\lt \int_0^{1/x} e^t\cos t\,dt\lt \frac{1}{x}e^{1/x}\cos(1/x),$$
and therefore
$$1\lt x\int_0^{1/x} e^t\cos t\,dt\lt e^{1/x}\cos(1/x).$$
Now Squeeze.

Comment: How do you know $\frac{1}{x} < \int_0^frac{1}{X} e^t\space \cost \space dt$? Why don't you use $e^0 \space cos0$ as the lower function?

Comment: The function $e^t\cos t$ is $\gt 1$ on $(0,1/x)$. This $1$ is exactly your $\cos 0 e^0$. So the integral is greater than $1$ times the length $1/x$ of the interval of integration. The same idea holds for the upper bound. The function is $\le e^{1/x}\cos(1/x)$ on the interval, so the integral is $\le e^{1/x}\cos(1/x)$ times the length $1/x$ of the interval.